# Occasionally slow Redis requests from Django

Tags: python, django, redis

On a Django application we are using Redis as caching backend using the `django-redis` package.
While this works generally well there are occasionally Redis requests which are quite slow, ranging from a hundreds of milliseconds up to 4-5 seconds (!).
The affected slow requests are simple GET and SET requests on various keys. A few of the keys have a little larger values like up to 180 KB but it happens also on keys with smaller values.

We use Sentry's performance data feature to identify the slow requests.
Those slow requests happen only one or two times a day, we didn't found a particular pattern or a way to reproduce it.

Redis' **slowlog** does not show any of those slow requests, the slowest query listed is about 200ms and is not related to the slow queries we see in Sentry.

The whole setup is hosted in the OpenTelekomCloud, which is some sort of an OpenStack instance.
The Django application is running on multiple PODs in a Kubernetes cluster and the Redis server is a managed instance of the hosting provider (Kubernetes and Redis server are in the same VPC and same subnet).
The Redis server is used almost exclusively as caching backend for the application, the only other use is as broker for Celery.

We checked the **monitoring** of the application and the Redis server:

- Redis server is pretty much relaxed, CPU usage is around 3-5%, memory usage is at 30%, connected clients ~500 in spikes, ops per second ~ 500, bandwidth 5%
- on the application side there is nothing obvious - CPU and bandwidth are relaxed

**Questions**:

Since the metrics of the Redis server itself do not show any resource shortage, we presume that the root cause might be rather network related or on the client side.

- What could cause the occasionally slow Redis requests?
- How could we better debug the cause of this?

Django cache configuration:

```
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
             'LOCATION': 'redis://10.0.5.7:6379/0',
             'TIMEOUT': 300,
             'OPTIONS': {'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
                         'SOCKET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT': 1,
                         'SOCKET_TIMEOUT': 1}}},
```

With the next deployment we will add "hiredis" and set keepalive parameters:

```
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
             'LOCATION': 'redis://10.0.5.7:6379/0',
             'TIMEOUT': 300,
             'OPTIONS': {'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
                         'SOCKET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT': 1,
                         'SOCKET_TIMEOUT': 1,
                         'PARSER_CLASS': 'redis.connection._HiredisParser',
                         'CONNECTION_POOL_KWARGS': {'health_check_interval': 60,
                                                    'socket_keepalive': True,
                                                    'socket_keepalive_options': {4: 30,
                                                                                 5: 30,
                                                                                 6: 50}}}},
```

Though while those will help in general, probably not for the distinct problem here.

The Redis server configuration is pretty standard, here are a few key settings:

```
maxclients 10000
maxmemory 2147483648
maxmemory-policy volatile-lru
timeout 300
appendfsync no
appendonly yes
```

Software versions:

- Package Django - 3.2.21
- Package Django-redis - 5.2.0
- Redis-Py - 5.0.0
- Redis server - 5.0

We also tried to reproduce the problem with a script using the application's cache backend settings and fire `GET` requests to the Redis server in up to 100 threads. To some extend the behavior could be reproduced ending in Redis requests taking a couple of seconds to finish.
This was also reproducable with a Redis server deployed as a POD in the Kubernetes cluster with default configuration.

Though this procedure might not be very accurate as it is unlikely that the productive application issues that many Redis queries at once. So we are assuming there must be yet another reason for the occasionally slow requests.

Comment: Hi @eht16, I seem to have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @SalvatoreIovene unfortunately not. It seems requests times got a bit better but we don't know what caused it. Either something on the hosting provider end or the upgrade to Django 4.2 which happened in the meantime. We actually use the Redis cache backend which is included in Django since 4.0.
But the problem itself is just a bit better, not resolved :(.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is not solved on my side either. I use Django 2.1 so I don't think it's a django problem.